# Get pristine value for form element in Angular

Tags: angularjs, forms

Does Angular have anything built in that returns the pristine value of an input element?

I see that there's a `$setPristine()`, but there's no function to **get** the pristine value? Right now, I just create a copy of the pristine value in my controller when the controller initializes. I really can't believe that's correct—that there isn't anything that will give me the original form field's value.

The form field is dirty but the value is the same as it was when the form field was pristine. The user has dirtied the field, but when the user leaves the field, the value is the same as it was before the field was dirtied. What does Angular provide that will tell me that?

Answer (score 1):

When your input element is dirty angular applies the ng-dirty class to it.  You can check to see if this class is present on the element.  It also applies the ng-pristine class on the element before it has been changed.

One thing to note: if you change the models value and set it back to it's original value, it will still be dirty.  That tripped me up a bit.

Answer (score 0):

not sure I understood what you're asking. but if you want to check if the element is clean or dirty just $scope.formName.inputName.$dirty (or $pristine) this will return true or false accordingly.

and if you want the value...well thats also simple :)